# Why can't I pull a method for another class?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, arraylist, assignment-operator

I can't work out why my compiler is having a problem. I'm trying to pull a simple get method from another class in order to define whether or not a book is loaned.

```
public String displayBooks(){

    for (Book b : book){

        if (b.isLoaned() = false){
            String loan = "Not currently loaned";
        }
        else{
            String loan = "Currently loaned";
        }
        return(book.getTitle() + "       " + book.getAuthor() + "       " );

    }

}
```

I'm receiving an error saying a variable was required when a value was found.
note: book is the name of an arraylist I'm storing book objects in.

Comment: `if (b.isLoaned() = false)` ???

Comment: besides that you are using `book.getTitle()`where you should use `b.getTitle`

Comment: whoops. Recently changed the name of the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
b.isLoaned() = false
```

uses an assignment operator where an equality operator should have been used. Assignment requires an Lvalue on the left-hand side (a variable, not a value).

You should in fact rewrite that part to just

```
!b.isLoaned()
```

and, considering the wider context, you may consider the following, which will forestall the compiler error awaiting you as soon as you fix the above:

```
String loan = (b.isLoaned()? "Currently" : "Not currently") + " loaned";
```

The above replaces your whole `if-else` block.

Comment: How embarrassing. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1):

It will say so cause `=` is assignment operator that you use in following line.

```
if (b.isLoaned() = false)
```

Change it to following:

```
if (b.isLoaned() == false)
```

or

```
if (!b.isLoaned())
```